# What is the sizeof a self-defined unsigned short with trap representation?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, sizeof

All the section numbers of C standard below is from this specific [C11 draft version](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Para. 1 of section 3.19.4 of C11 states that:

> **trap representation**
>
> an object representation that need not represent a value of the object type

Para. 1 of section 6.2.6.2 of C11 states that:

> For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object
> representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need
> not be any of the latter).  ...

Para. 2 of section 6.5.3.4 of C11 states that :

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
> the operand

Hypothetically, let's say I designed a CPU architecture that (wastefully) uses three bytes (24-bits) to store a `unsigned short`. This wasteful `unsigned short`'s range is still [0, 65535]. Its last two bytes are a normal `uint16_t` and the first byte is reserved for all possible kinds of trap representations.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say the `unsigned short` is valid only if the first byte is `0000 0000`; the `unsigned short` is uninitialized (and thus is a trap representation) if the first byte is not `0000 0000`.

The question is, for a variable of my wasteful `unsigned short`:

```
unsigned short a = 123;
```

what is the expected result from`sizeof`?:

```
sizeof a;
```

And more importantly, which paragraph of which section of the C standard should be used to support the expected result?

**EDIT1:**
All references to `uint16_t` is changed to `unsigned short` as some users point out that `uint16_t` can't have padding bits.

Comment: From the C standard (emphasis added): *"The typedef name intN_t designates a signed integer type with width N , **no padding bits**, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits."* So your hypothetical wasteful `uint16_t` is not legal.

Comment: @user3386109 please let me know exactly which section of which C standard you are referring to. Para. 1 of section 6.2.6.2 of C11 as provided in my question says we can have padding bits.

Comment: Section 7.20 of C11 has all the details about the fixed-width types defined in `<stdint.h>`

Comment: Per C 2018 7.20.1.1 1 and 2, the exact-width integer types do not have padding bits. So `uint16_t` is exactly 16 bits and cannot have any trap representations.

Comment: okay all references to `uint16_t` is now revised to `unsigned short`.

Comment: Section 5.2.4.2.1 tells you how many bits are in a byte. `CHAR_BIT` must divide evenly into the number of bits in your wasteful `short`, and the quotient is your answer.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Your edit of the question does not make sense because the situation was considered hypnotically. So it is unimportant how actually objects of the type uint16_t are stored.:)

Comment: In addition to size of e.g. `unsigned short`, the implementation must define limits such as `USHRT_MAX` (C17 5.2.4.2.1) and there is no requirement that this equals "2^(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(unsigned short))-1".

Comment: @nielsen the range of [0, 65535] is part of the question's settings. I believe that the C standard should still be self-consistent even if `USHRT_MAX` is defined other than 65535. Just for the purpose of reducing confusion, this aspect is not initially explored in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

The C language definition of *byte*, C17 3.6:

> **byte**
> addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character
> set of the execution environment

As for how many bits a byte has, it is not defined by C, other than that it must be *at least* 8. C17 5.2.4.2.1:

> - number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>   `CHAR_BIT   8`

`sizeof` is guaranteed to return the number of bytes used by the operand, so in case your `unsigned short` is 3 bytes, it will return 3. C17 6.5.3.4

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand

Therefore the expected result of `sizeof` is 3. The number of bits in that datatype will be `3 * CHAR_BIT`. `sizeof` returns the object size, which may be larger than the value of part of the object, as seen with any `struct` using padding.

Notably, the integer value range of a type need not necessarily correspond to the size in bytes. Just look at any signed type, the value range is (at least) 1 bit shorter than the total amount of bits used by that type.

Comment: as some users suggest, say I use 3 * 8 = 24 bits to store an `unsigned short` which ranges from 0 to 65535, meaning that we only need 16 bits to represent all possible values. In the meantime, `CHAR_BIT` is set to 12. does `sizeof (unsigned short)` return 2 instead of 3?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Systems where bit size doesn't correspond to byte size don't make any sense even in theory. If you have CHAR_BIT as 12, then you have to use at least 2 * 12 bits to store an `unsigned short`. You cannot have a type which is 2 * 3/4 of a byte large.

Comment: In the system,  what I want to say is that: one byte is 12-bit long, I use the 8-11 bits of the 1st byte and 0-11 bits of the 2nd byte (i.e., a total of 16 bits, but only 4/3 bytes) to represent [0, 65535]. The 0-7 bits of the 1st bytes are padding bits. In this case, `sizeof (unsigned short)` should be 2?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Yes that would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the sizeof operator does not depend on the value stored in the object.

As you wrote yourself

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand

So according to your description

> Hypothetically, let's say I designed a CPU architecture that
> (wastefully) uses three bytes

the sizeof operator will return 3 though the name of the type will confuse users.

A more real situation is with structures. They can have many paddings between their data members and these paddings are taken into account to determine how much memory must be allocated for an object of the structure type. And for example a data member of a structure type can be `uint16_t`. So to determine the size of the structure the compiler needs to know how much memory actually is occupied by its data members.

Also consider the pointer arithmetic. If you have an array like

```
uint16_t a[2];
```

then the expression `a + 1` must point to the second element of the array. The expression is evaluated like `( char * )a + sizeof( uint16_t )`.  If `sizeof( uint16_t )` will not be equal to3 you will get an incorrect value.

Comment: so what is that? 2? 3?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind The value will be 3. It is how many bytes is allocated to store the object.

Comment: The name is not confusing in the sense that my `uint16_t`'s range is still [0, 65535], so from a user's perspective it is just a normal '16-bit" integer. The thing starts to become confusing if `sizeof a` returns 3. Thus I am wondering if 3 is really the expected answer.

Comment: and I start to think, perhaps this is not relevant to a CPU architecture at all? it is just the implementation of a C compiler. I can decide to create my own (weird but perfectly standard-conforming) compiler this way (i.e., to have three-byte `uint16_t`) on top of a stock x86 CPU.

Comment: the last part (on `uint16_t a[2];`) makes perfect sense--seems `sizeof` has to return 3 to make the rest of components work together.

Comment: If such a type required a 16bit alignment, would that make the size 4?

Comment: @Gerhardh it will only need 16-bit alignment if `CHAR_BIT == 16`?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind why would that be true? Many architectures require 16 bit alignment for 16 bit memory accesses while having `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: @Gerhardh I am not sure about this, perhaps you could comment below Eric Postpischil's  answer as well

Comment: @Gerhardh An array is not allowed to contain padding between its elements. The standard (C17 6.2.5-20) says that an array type is a *contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects*.

Comment: @nielsen that is why I think the underlying type must be enlarged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard is clear about this; the only unclear things are in the question, particularly whether it uses “byte” in the sense of the C standard (a unit of at least eight bits, used as the building block of the C object model) or in the sense of eight bits.

The C standard says all objects other than bit-fields are composed of bytes, and a `char` is one byte, and it must be at least eight bits. If a byte is eight bits, then a 24-bit object must have a size of three bytes. If a byte can be bigger than eight bits, the possibilities that allow a 24-bit object are 12 bits and 24 bits, making the size of a 24-bit object two bytes and one byte, respectively.

Comment: I try to avoid dragging more aspects into the question by saying "three bytes (24-bits)" in the original question (i.e., I didn't add the (24 bits) part after reading your answer). Therefore, I guess the general assumption is that here one byte contains 8 bits in the context of this question. But the `CHAR_BIT` part in the comment does make the discussion more complete though.

Comment: If that (hypothetical) architecture required a 16 bit alignment to access variables of such type, wouldn't the required padding byte also count to the size, making it 4?

Comment: @Gerhardh: The size of an individual object must be a multiple of its alignment requirement. If an object’s alignment requirement is 16 bits, it cannot be a 24-bit object. The type of 16-bit width the question posits would have to have 16 padding bits, not eight. The question posits eight padding bits, not 16, so its size must be 24 bits, not 32.

Comment: These extra 8 bit from the question must contain a specific pattern. Otherwise the value is a trap value. Does that qualify as padding bits? But I get you point that this must be already included in the type construction and not only into sizeof.